# What are some examples of Enlightenment works that would definitively not be Romantic?

Tags: 19th-century, enlightenment

I've been researching the [Romantic era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanticism) and am confused by how expansively people seem to define it. It seems that the scholarly emphasis is more on encompassing as much as possible with this conception of an era rather than attempting to distinguish it from other eras. It is repeatedly said that it was diametrically opposed to and in response to the Enlightenment, but it seems that it occurred concurrently with the Enlightenment (e.g. Hume, Rosseau, the French Revolution), and in consideration of the criteria cited it seems that the Enlightenment would have been very disproportionately tiny indeed. I cannot think of any philosophes who objected to the use of intuition relative to reason.

Comment: "I cannot think of any philosophes who objected to the use of intuition relative to reason." Try researching [Rationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalism).  Typically, the Romantic period is thought of as starting near the end of the Enlightenment.  But in any case, there's no reason to expect that the two movements *wouldn't* exist at the same time. The United Nations drafted the [Four Freedoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Freedoms) during the height of totalitarianism in Europe.

Comment: [Please document your preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  [Example questions don't have authoritative answers](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4272/1401)

Comment: @Juhasz I've researched rationalism but it only proved my point. Immanuel Kant, for example, denied the ability to use reason alone. I completely agree that the two movements existed at the same time, which is why I'm critiquing the claim that they existed as two chronologically distinguishable eras at all.

Answer (score 0):

How about Newton's *Principia*? It's a scientific work and is definitely not romantic by any stretch of the word. Although there is a famous painting of Newton which is definitely in the romantic tradition.

Comment: It would be a stretch to say that was part of the Enlightenment. Also the fact that it's about physical description means that it would not concern itself with either supporting or opposing romanticism, any more than a farmer's manual would.